# MIT vs. BSD vs. Dual License

Tags: open-source, licensing, mit-license, bsd-license

My understanding is that:

- [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)-licensed projects can be used/redistributed in [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)-licensed projects.
- BSD-licensed projects can be used/redistributed in MIT-licensed projects.
- The MIT and the BSD 2-clause licenses are [essentially identical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License#Comparison_to_other_licenses).
- BSD 3-clause **=** BSD 2-clause **+** the "no endorsement" clause
- Issuing a dual license allows users to [choose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing) from those licenses—not be bound to both.

If all of the above is correct, then what is the point of using a **dual** MIT/BSD license? Even if the BSD refers to the 3-clause version, then can't a user legally choose to only abide by the MIT license?

It seems that if you really want the "no endorsement" clause to apply then you have to license it as just BSD (not dual). If you don't care about the "no endorsement" clause, then MIT alone is sufficient and MIT/BSD is redundant.

Similarly, since the MIT and BSD licenses are both "[GPL-compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Compatibility_and_multi-licensing)" and can be redistributed in [GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)-licensed projects, then dual licensing MIT/GPL also seems redundant.

Comment: Can you provide an MIT + BSD licenses example? It's usually redundant to dual license under two similarly permissive licenses, but I've seen dual licensing abused as a way to explicitly state that code could be redistributed under each one of the licenses.

Comment: @Yannis Yea I wondered if people dual-licensed them just to be more explicit for people who don't know. But I think it just makes it more confusing for them.

Comment: Interesting read: http://www.tomhull.com/ocston/docs/mozgpl.html

Comment: related: [How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/120308/31260)

Comment: In my experience people mainly use dual licensing for incompatible licenses. e.g. MPL+(L)GPL or a paid license with no copyleft together with (A)GPL.

Answer (score 71):

> My understanding is that:

> 1. MIT-licensed projects can be used/redistributed in BSD-licensed projects.

**True** (but unless there are modifications, the users can get it from the sources also.

> 2. BSD-licensed projects can be used/redistributed in MIT-licensed projects.

**False** The BSD 3-clause places additional restrictions on redistribution.

> 3. The MIT and the BSD 2-clause licenses are essentially identical.

**True** Although there is some ambiguity around whether some parts of the MIT license apply to binaries.

> 4. BSD 3-clause = BSD 2-clause + the "no endorsement" clause

**True**.

> 5. Issuing a dual license allows users to choose from those licenses—not be bound to both.

**True**.

> Similarly, since the MIT and BSD licenses are both "GPL-compatible" and can be redistributed in GPL-licensed projects, then dual-licensing MIT/GPL also seems redundant.

**No**. Here is a major difference. MIT license and Apache License only requires that you give credit to original copyright holders. If you choose, you *can* redistribute source; but if you choose you can keep your new derived product *without* opening code. Hence, it is possible to use code developed under MIT and Apache—under a commercial license.

If you ever use code with GPL-based license and happen to modify it, you *must* distribute *your modified code* as well under GPL. In other words, once any GPL codebase is used under a project, and if you want to publish that as a product, it has to be published with the source code and it has to be published under GPL. It cannot ever be a commercial license or closed source, and it cannot be any other license which is less strict than GPL.

An example can take MIT, Apache or BSD license code, modified and distributed under GPL. Once a codebase is distributed as GPL, its further derived versions cannot be distributed under MIT, Apache or BSD license but must be GPL only.

#### Edit:

An example case of dual license: Suppose Nice Office is released under dual license—MIT and GPL. It has two possibilities. Some people can create NicePro Office, which can be commercial and sell. Whereas some other open source community creates a fork NiceOpen Office. In this case, it can enforce upon GPL distribution (of the original Nice Office as well as NiceOpen Office version) hence if you start with NiceOpen Office, you must comply to GPL only and not MIT license.

The point is in case of dual license the first person who derives a license has a choice. He can choose either way - however, the second person needs to adhere to the choice the first person made. He/She cannot override the original rights of either generation and cannot in any way reduce the obligation of the applicable license.

#### EDIT 2

Adding an interesting read - GPL and MPL Licenses has a serious conflict. [Read this](http://www.tomhull.com/ocston/docs/mozgpl.html).

Comment: Nice answer.  Suggest you clarify the last paragraph to state that "in the event that you publish modified software under the GPL, you *must* also publish the modified source code".

Comment: Edited the answer as per your comment. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @Dipan If a project is dual licensed under MIT/GPL, then it **can** be used in a proprietary project b/c the user can choose to follow only the MIT. If a project holds only the MIT license, then it can be redistributed under others licenses including the GPL. That's what I meant by redundant.

Comment: @DipanMehta What do you mean by "contribution credits" in #2? It sounds like you're referring to the BSD 4-clause license, which is not verified by the FSF like the 3-clause and 2-clause are. I'm talking about the 3-clause and the 2-clause ones, in which case I'm pretty sure that all five statements are **true**.

Comment: @ryanve - The original BSD license also states as *"and that any documentation, advertising materials, and other materials related to such distribution and use acknowledge that the software was developed by the <organization>."* So contributor credits are must for any version of BSD license.

Comment: So where did I miss why dual-licensing under MIT/GPL is not redundant, i.e. is different from distributing under MIT? In either case anybody can abide just MIT unless combining with something GPL, in which it will be GPL in either case too.

Comment: @JanHudec i appended the answer according to your query.

Comment: You can use BSD-licensed code in conjunction with MIT-licensed code; you just have to mention in the project's materials that "BazApp uses libfoobar, which is distributed under a BSD license" or something like that. The BSD and MIT licenses are applied on a per-file, rather than per-project, level.

Comment: @Dipan_Mehta As ryanve already told you, you're talking about the original 4-clause BSD license, while the OP is talking about the revised 3- and 2-clause BSD licenses. The 2-clause BSD license is actually equivalent to the MIT one. Even the OSI page states so.

Comment: The part about MIT/BSD code becoming GPL once incorporated into a GPL work is inaccurate and may be misleading; unless granted permission by the copyright holder, MIT/BSD code incorporated into a GPL work stays MIT/BSD, and that portion can be reused in other works under the MIT/BSD licenses; only the whole work is considered GPL. See this page for more info: https://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2007/gpl-non-gpl-collaboration.html

Comment: Point #2 (BSD code cannot be included in MIT code) runs contrary to every piece of information I've ever read about 3-clause and 2-clause BSD. Point #2 would be true about the (now-ancient and forgotten) 4-clause BSD, but the OP has made it clear this question is not about the 4-clause BSD. It seems quite harmful to have such a hugely misleading piece of information in an otherwise very good and credible answer.

Comment: "MIT license allows for distribution without contribution credits; BSD doesn't.". Is it even true? Can't find a trace of something relevant in texts of both licenses. Could you please add part of license you are referring to? Or change answer because if you you are wrong lot of people will be confused.

Answer (score 6):

Your five points are all **true**.

The other answer seems to be assuming you are including the older, rarely used *4 clause BSD license*.

If you interpret "BSD licenses" as referring to the more commonly used 3-clause or 2-clause variants of the BSD license, all five claims in the question are true.

> If all of the above is correct, then what is the point of using a dual MIT/BSD license?

Technically there should be no need for it.  Either can be used in the same situations.

> Even if the BSD refers to the 3-clause version, then can't a user legally choose to only abide by the MIT license?

That sounds correct.

> It seems that if you really want the "no endorsement" clause to apply then you have to license it as just BSD (not dual). If you don't care about the "no endorsement" clause, then MIT alone is sufficient and MIT/BSD is redundant.

That's right.  If you care about that particular clause it wouldn't make sense to also license the same work under licenses without that clause.

> Similarly, since the MIT and BSD licenses are both "GPL-compatible" and can be redistributed in GPL-licensed projects, then dual licensing MIT/GPL also seems redundant.

Yes.

Though, sometimes a software product will claim to be dual licensed as MIT and GPL (or some permissive license and GPL), but in reality they are referring to two different versions of the software.

For example, some software can be compiled and distributed with a permissive license like BSD or MIT, but if you omit some libraries and therefore some functionality, it can be distributed as GPL.  The omitted libraries will usually be third party libraries that are not GPL compatible but could still otherwise be distributed.